# Not able to add device in IBM bluemix?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot

I am not able to add Raspberry Pi to IBM Bluemix. I have generated the access keys and followed all the steps. But when I click on the portal add a device, it asks for device types on creating new one I am still not able to add the device. Has the device adding process changed in new IBM Bluemix portal because none of the recipes defines it. Please provide the latest steps if someone has.

Comment: Can you please provide what device you are using, what language you are trying to connect from?  Additionally please rephrase your community as stackoverflow is a programming community and this question is not programming delated.  Please add in what you have tried

Comment: As it is mentioned above the device is RaspberryPi and the adding process is via UI no programming language.

Comment: Can you please share more details on what you are doing? It's hard to debug or help with the details so far

Comment: Is this the internet of things foundation portal rather than Bluemix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there was a change in the device portal. Previously there may have been a drop down that had raspberry pi as an option.  Now if you want to add a device and don't already have a raspberry pi device type defined just click "add device" 
then "create device type"  and add the info to define your device.  Note that the metadata field is optional.

Once you have gone through the steps to add "device type", that type will then be available to select when you add device and you can choose it as the type to add, then click next and the screen will have a place to add device ID.
I am adding a few screen shots for reference. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Valerie. Can this be documented and can you give me the steps so that I can add Raspberry Pi and where I have to enter the device ID and other details in the portal.

Comment: We will make a note to update the documentation so it is easier for user's to understand.  You should be able to follow these steps:  1. Click Add Device  2. click Create Device Type  3.  Enter Name and Description  4. continue through steps until that device ID type is created and then on the next screen it will allow you to input device ID

Comment: Thanks Valeria, where can I get device ID from my raspberry pi as I am newbie in this field. Thanks :-)

Comment: There are different ways to obtain the ID - it is generally the MAC address without the colons.  It may even be printed on the outside of your pi.   Here are some examples for ways to obtain it programmatically:  http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/finding-the-mac-address-of-a-raspberry-pi/                     https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-raspberrypi/blob/master/samples/c/iotGetDeviceID.sh

Answer (score 0):

Your device id would be the mac address of the Raspberry pi ( without the colons ). e.g: A mac address would be b8:27:eb:98:46:0a, and the device id would be b827eb98460a. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.